# Oracle Apex - Is it possible to send a value from a page item from the client side to the server side without a submit?

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I added a JavaScript function to capture the ROWID of the rows that are selected in the GRID and passed it to a page item.

```
var gridView = apex.region("emp").call("getCurrentView"),
    selectedRecords = gridView.getSelectedRecords(),
    idValues = "";

for (var i = 0; i < selectedRecords.length; i++) {
    var record = selectedRecords[i];
    var idValue = record[0];
    idValues += idValue;

    if (i < selectedRecords.length - 1) {
        idValues += ",";
    }
}
$s("P43_ROW_SELECT", idValues);
```

However, I need to use the values ​​that this item receives in a process (server side), so I have to submit the page first so that the item actually receives the values, so that I can use them in the process.

My question, if it is possible to pass the values ​​that the item receives in my process in PL/SQl (server side), without the need to submit the page, is there another way besides submitting?

Comment: when is this javascript executed ?

Comment: I created a dynamic action on a button, where I select the lines in the grid and click on the button to: capture, move to the item and submit.

Comment: create a dynamic action on change of P43_ROW_SELECT as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I did it differently, instead of passing it to a page item, I passed it as a parameter in the process call, something like this:

```
apex.server.process( "processSubmitAjax", {
    x01: idValues 
},
{
   [...]
}
```

And I called in the process

```
DECLARE
  l_x01         VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_x01 := APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01;

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an AJAX process as explained in the docs, check the apex.server.process function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aexjs/apex.server.html#.process).

Another solution, the best fitting one, would be to add a **Execute Server-side Code** action to your DA and to list the item (P43_ROW_SELECT) in the Items to Submit section. [Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex-tips-call-plsql-code-using-a-dynamic-action) you can find a more detailed explanation.